# How to fix "inconsistency occurred between the server state and the php.ini state" in Zendcore Extension Configuration of Oci8

Tags: oracle, database-server

Unable to run .php oracle server connection file because it is giving an error in Zendcore Extension Configuration i.e  "Extensions marked with a symbol '!' indicate that an inconsistency occurred between the server state and the php.ini state. Possible causes are that the php.ini was changed earlier and the server was not restarted, or that the extension failed to load. To test this, try to restart the server. If they remain unloaded, then these extensions could not be loaded because of some failure"

I am new in connecting Zendcore with Oracle/SQL. I tried restarting zendcore services from the control panel.

[image]